# Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors" when opening ADO connection

Tags: ms-access, vb6, oledb, oledbconnection, aceoledb

I have this connection string

```
strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\mydb.accdr;Persist Security Info=False;"
```

When I try to open the connection, I get this error:

> Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors"

when opening ADO connection.
I tried all possible solutions found on Google, but no success. Registry is fine.

Any advice?

Here is how I use the code: (`cn` is a global `ADODB.Connection`)

```
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open strConnect, "Admin", ""
```

PC is running windows XP with no MS Office installed.

**EDIT**

I have tested the connection string outside of the application and it works fine. just doesn't want to connect when opening the connection from code.

Also had a look at http://www.adopenstatic.com/faq/80040e21.asp, seems my issue is **scenario 2** but still no idea how to fix it.

Other references I looked at, but where not helpful are:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/269495

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my connection string was the problem, had a property that is not supported. It should be like this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\mydb.accdr;
```

without the `Persist Security Info=False;` which is not supported.

Hope somebody finds this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should post more of the code,
like how you use that string.
Also you could try "Source=C:\mydb.accdr". There should bei 2x "\". I still don´t get it why the reader cuts this away.
Or write an example program,
where you try to connect to another testing database,
to see if it really works fine.

Comment: Shouldn´t it be more like this: private ADODB.Connection cn = new ADODB.Connection(); and if it´s like the oledb stuff, maybe you need to just do cn.Open(strConnect,  null, null, 0); [link]https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308611[/link] maybe helps. there´s an example, but i´m not into that adodb stuff, i only do some stuff with the oledb stuff for an exam...

Comment: I need to also add that this only happens on one pc. works fine on others

Comment: then must be Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 be missing on that machine or not correctly adressed.